# Invalid Json string when posting to Facebook using Facebook SDK C#

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone run into this problem?

Everything worked fine for the last couple years until today when it suddenly throws the "Invalid Json string" error whenever we try to post to Facebook. The exception detail is not helpful so I'm not sure what to do next. Full error:

```
Invalid Json string 
at Facebook.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(String json)
at Facebook.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(String json, Type type, IJsonSerializerStrategy    jsonSerializerStrategy)
at Facebook.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(String json, Type type)
at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString,    Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I downloaded Facebook SDK code and debug it. Turns out the real exception is "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" when posting a web request to Facebook. I'm looking at this error now to see what it means.

Comment: Facebook Bug. Read this. https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/213909805469476/

Comment: Are you sure a 500 error is being returned? the repro cases I saw for the bug report linked here all had a HTTP 200 error with a zero byte response

Comment: Thank you! I got the 500 error from time to time but aside from that, the main issue is the null response from FB as you mentioned. I was looking for a reported bug but could not find anything. You saved me a lot of time.